# How to find the location of the device connected to router

Tags: network, wifi

Someone is using my wifi other than my devices, so i checked the connected devices in the d-link and found the ip address of the user and saved it.
Now how do I find the location of the user?

Comment: The IP address given out by your router? That IP is useless. You need to track the signal. There are phone apps that might do this.

Comment: Why was this tagged with "web application" and "passwords"? How were those relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is to this issue is wrong. If someone is accessing your WiFi without your consent, pinpointing their location will not necessarily help you.

Instead you should harden your access point so that your current "guest" and others cannot access it:

- Set a strong password
- Select a strong authentication/encryption mechanism
- Enable MAC filtering
- Change and hide your wireless network SSID name
- Turn off guest networking

This will not only solve your current problem but protect you against similar problems in the future.

Comment: Changing and hiding the SSID is of little to no value in most instances as it's readily sniffed. In many cases it's actually worse. If a mobile device is set up to use **My Hidden SSID**, that mobile device will often periodically send out connection attempts where ever it goes, beaconing its attempts to connect to **My Hidden SSID**. For a stationary system, it doesn't hurt but it really doesn't help either. Ideally *Guest Networking* should have similar strong authentication so turning it off should not matter, but some router guests are insecure.

Answer (score 0):

That's the IP which was given by your router itself to the "unknown device", it's only an internal IP, not a public one, you're not gonna get anything out of it.

- Change the login credentials of the router configuration page
- Change the current WEP/WPA/WPA2 password. And please, only use WPA2.
- Disable WPS if present (easily crackable)
- Don't hide your SSID, it's useless. Actually an expert would by attracted by "hidden" SSID.
- You could enable MAC filtering but it's dead simple to change your MAC